# Why does Django disallow blocks inside includes?

Tags: django, django-templates

I may be missing something here, but is there a special reason that Django does not allow this even though the context is passed to the include? It seems useful (for readability) to be able to render a `block` within an `include` because it makes the markup less dense—sorta similar to the way Angular uses directives.

Is there perhaps another template tag that accomplishes this?

---

**Example.**
In the image below, `navbar` is site-wide but `navbar2` is view-dependent and resides within the included `content.html`. This allows for neater mark-up as you're not loading every block into the skeleton... but alas it doesn't work.

[image: Basic Admin Dashboard]

**base.html**

```
<html>  
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            {% block navbar %}
            {% endblock %}
        </nav>

        {% include "content.html" %}

        {% include "footer.html" %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**content.html**

```
<header>{{ request.view_name }}</header>

<nav>
    {% block navbar2 %} 
    {% endblock %}
</nav>

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

**model-list.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block navbar2 %}
    {% for action in view_actions %}
        <li>{{ action }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `include` isn't inheriting from the base so it has no contract to adhere to.

By `extending` you are stating that your template will consist of building blocks that the base class is looking for.

Comment: It's interesting that it doesn't import all includes first, then parse the resulting template. I've noticed that Jinja2 supports this.

Comment: @DanielvanFlymen - I haven't used Jinja2 so I can't comment on how that works I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way. When you are using "include" you will be getting the executed output, no placeholders / variables.

Having said that you could create a content_base.html to only affect the content templates but it is misguided to think that there is too much performance hit in unnecessary block inheritance in Django templates. Also {% block %} is faster than using {% include %}.